# Checking table for existent columns, if not, add column

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to build a newsletter. The user has to fill a form where `$emaila` is his email.

```
<?php
$emaila="test@test.com";
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","dbname");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$val = mysqli_query("select $emaila from emails limit 1");
if($val !== FALSE)
{
mysqli_query($con,"ALTER TABLE emails ADD (".$emaila." VARCHAR(100))");
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

It suposes to check if the email is already in the table "emails" as column, and if it isn't, it should put his email in the table as column. Not sure what I did wrong...

Comment: `test@test.com` is that really a column? `$val = mysqli_query("select` no connection here

Comment: It should be a column. If it is not, it should be added.

Comment: `select $emaila from emails` translates to `select test@test.com from emails`. Check for errors on the queries `mysqli_error($con)` and you'll see. But that never happens because you didn't pass connection to the query.

Comment: If you select like that you will get an error if the column doesn't exist. That doesn't make sense. You want to add a column for each email which there is no column? That also doesn't make sense.

Comment: if you want to check if a row exists, then you need to do `select email_column from emails WHERE email_column='test@test.com'` and with `num_rows()` afterwards.

Comment: No. I want to add the $emaila as column if there isn't any column $emaila, so then I could get all the columns with implode to send an email to the entire columns (emails)

Comment: That is not the way to do that - that is ***bad design***. You would put the email addresses into one column, select from that column and loop through the results to send emails. Show us how you create the table.

Comment: I know but as said, I did something like this in MySQL and it worked. That was some time ago, now it is not working only if I downgrade the PHP version. I don't quite know that much about MySQLi. I decided to do the script again but things are not quite the same as in mysql. Can you show me a better way?

Comment: I already did below.

Comment: It gives an error: Unknown column 'email_column_name' in 'where clause'

Comment: Becasue you have to use the name of the column you have already setup to use for the email addresses.

Comment: If you do not know how to do this go take some online tutorials before you write one more line of code. This is PHP/MySQL 101

Comment: The email adresses ARE the columns.

Comment: *"The email adresses ARE the columns."* - OMG, really? That isn't how it works. You need 1 column named `email` with separate "rows" holding the email addresses. You need to start over.

Comment: I know... It's an old database with over 500 emails as columns already... The above code should check if $emaila is already a column and if it isn't it should be added.

Comment: Who gave you that database? who built it? OMG

Comment: It was a database of an older newsletter. The owner of the newsletter was a friend of mine and he gave it to me. Now I decided to start the newsletter again but the older PHP code is not working properly on the newer PHP version. That's why I wanted to do it in MySQLi.

Comment: It would be better if you got all of the existing columns as rows in a new table and then go from there.

Comment: I think that would be the best way... Thanks

Comment: You're going to have to figure out a way to save those columns as values and I honestly have no idea how to do that. I guess I could figure out a way, but that stands to take a lot of time.

Comment: Maybe I should get all the columns as string, and use explode.

Comment: This Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/22399477/1415724 could help you. You could then put that `.csv` file in Excel and modify it, and then reimport into phpmyadmin somehow, or parse it with PHP http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/16391528/1415724 and http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-export-table-to-csv/

Comment: I edited that a few times ^ you'll need to reload it. And Jay edited his answer also with an example.

Comment: This is the way it was done before:
 `   <?php
$emaila="test@test.com";
$hostname="localhost";
$username="username";
$password="pass";
$dbname="dbname";
$connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection);
$val = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM `Emails` LIKE '$emaila'");
if($val !== FALSE)
{
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `Emails` ADD `$emaila` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL");
}
?>   `

Comment: I can't paste the code...
https://s27.postimg.org/tkdvs5t5f/aaaaaaaaaaa.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use `ALTER TABLE` to add data to a table. You use `INSERT`

```
INSERT INTO `emails` (`column_name`) VALUES '$emaila'
```

Your test should be to see if the email exists in the table:

```
$val = mysqli_query($con,"select * from emails where email_column_name = '$emaila' ") or die (mysqli_error($con));
if($val)
{
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `emails` (`email_column_name`) VALUES '$emaila'")  or die (mysqli_error($con));
mysqli_close($con);
}
```

---

In addition: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

---

EDIT: Based on comments you will need to get the column names from the current table, loop through the result set and for each confirm the column name is an email address and then insert that address into a new table. Here is something to get you started:

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='database_name' 
AND `TABLE_NAME`='emails';
```

This query will return a set of column names from the emails table (don't forget to change the database name) that you can loop through.

Comment: I am not used to MySQL improved that much and I tried to learn but can't find that much about it...  I think there is a problem at `$val = mysqli_query("select $emaila from emails limit 1");` too.

Comment: Fix one thing and then chase down the other errors.

Comment: I tested and still doesn't work... No connection error. It doesn't add $emaila as column in the table "emails"...

Comment: You're trying to add a column? Or you're trying to add data to a column?

Comment: I am trying to add a column.