# How do I copy a column from my phpmyadmin table and paste it into my excel worksheet?

Tags: excel, phpmyadmin

I have a table in `phpmyadmin` which has around 5000 rows, having four columns A,B,C and D. I want to copy the C column completely and paste it into my excel worksheet. How do I do that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is select what you want and export in csv
You can see this post [phpmyadmin exporting to csv for excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399477/phpmyadmin-exporting-to-csv-for-excel)

Comment: If there is another question on SO that has answers that can answer this question, you should flag this post as duplicate and provide that question there, or comment on OP's question this as a suggestion.